# Multiple Files upload Angular + Laravel

Tags: php, angular, laravel, file, upload

I'm working with Angular. I've to upload multiple images on via an API (made/written in Laravel).
The following body is accepted by the api

```
portfolio_id: 2
portfolio_image: [ {file1}, {file2} ] //Accepts in this format. File Objects in an array
```

My angular code is:

HTML

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <label class="file-upload-label">Upload Profile Picture</label>
  <input multiple (change)="fileSelected($event)" type="file" id="file" name="profile_pic"/>
  <label for="file" class="btn-2">Upload</label>
 </div>
```

Component.ts

```
  selectedFile;

  fileSelected(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files;
    console.log("Selected Files are:",this.selectedFile)
  }
```

On button submit I'm running the following function from component.ts file:

```
  portfolioImage(){

  const formData =  new  FormData();
  formData.append("portfolio_id",  this.portfolioId);
  formData.append("portfolio_image", this.selectedFile)
  this.httpClient.post(this.URL, formData, httpOptionsMulti).subscribe(res =>  {
      console.log(res);
      alert('Files uploaded Successfully!');
  })
}
```

**Console Output:** On file selection change event I see the following in console.log

```
FileList [ File, File ]
```

Upon expanding the array I see the following:

```
 FileList(2)
    0: File { name: "1.jpg", lastModified: 1578490559152, size: 317383, … }
    1: File { name: "2.jpg", lastModified: 1578490599778, size: 288174, … }
    length: 2
```

**Issue:** 
Up on submission I see nothing in params on the network tab although **I do get a images uploaded successfully message.**

**Things I've tried**
I tried to upload via loop and changed the `fileSelected(event)` function to:

```
 myFiles:string [] = [];
  fileSelected(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) { 
        this.myFiles.push(event.target.files[i]);
    }
}
```

and upload function to:

```
portfolioImage(){
  console.log("myfile",this.myFiles);
  const formData =  new  FormData();
  formData.append("portfolio_id",  this.portfolioId);
  for(var i =  0; i <  this.myFiles.length; i++)  {  
      formData.append("portfolio_image",  this.myFiles[i]);
  } 
  this.httpClient.post(this.URL, formData, httpOptionsMulti).subscribe(res =>  {
      console.log(res);
      alert('Files uploaded Successfully!');
  })
}
```

But still no luck.

**Summary:** How to upload multiple files using angular on frontend and laravel api on backend. The laravel api accepts the files as objects in array: [ {file}, {file} ]. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You did a little mistake in your upload function, consider the given

```js
portfolioImage(){
  const formData =  new  FormData();
  formData.append("portfolio_id",  this.portfolioId);
  for(var i =  0; i <  this.myFiles.length; i++)  {  
      formData.append("portfolio_image[]",  this.myFiles[i]);
  } 
  this.httpClient.post(this.URL, formData, httpOptionsMulti).subscribe(res =>  {
      console.log(res);
      alert('Files uploaded Successfully!');
  })
}
```

The `portfolio_image` should be used as given to make it multiple file array in formData. from your Laravel controller function, use as given to check uploaded temp files.

```php
public function uploader(Request $request){
    $data = [
        $request->allFiles(),
    ];
    return response()->json($data);
}
```